# Do you lose rep for a closed question?

Tags: support, reputation

As an example [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/31232/why-do-they-do-charlie-brown-sketches-in-court), do you lose reputation if you've answered a question that has later been closed? Would Fake Name keep his 3 upvotes?

I know I ask a lot about losing/gaining rep, I'm just interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reputation (both up, or down) is maintained against closed questions. Once a question (or answer) is deleted, then the associated reputation changes are reversed.

Answer (score 3):

It's also worth pointing out that if you delete your own question or answer it will remove any gain or loss of rep that you got from it.  It makes for a nice incentive for a poorly matched question or answer to be removed by the submitter to recover their reputation and improve the overall quality of the site.